# Vue's transitions don't work when you refresh the browser?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

Vue's [Transitions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Hooks) don't seem to work when you refresh your browser.

```
<transition
  v-on:before-enter="beforeEnter"
  v-on:enter="enter"
  v-on:leave="leave"
>
  <!-- ... -->
</transition>

methods: {
  beforeEnter: function (el) {
    console.log('before enter')
  },
  enter: function (el, done) {
    console.log('enter')
    done()
  },
  leave: function (el, done) {
    console.log('leave')
    done()
  }
}
```

For instance, when I **click** to go to http://myvue.com/#/foo I get the transitions and all the console logs. But I **don't** get the transitions and the logs when I **refresh** my browser on http://myvue.com/#/foo

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using the `appear` property as described in [Transitions on Initial Render](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitions-on-Initial-Render)?

Comment: @Sebastian it seems to work just adding appear on that transition tag - odd

Comment: have a look here for more details: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/733

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<transition
  appear
  v-on:before-enter="beforeEnter"
  v-on:enter="enter"
  v-on:leave="leave"
>
  <!-- ... -->
</transition>
```